# specflow - get the scenario duration

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

How do I read the scenario running time programmatically?

I can see it in visual studio however I am not able to read this value.

(I have currently implemented a stopWatch to get the timer, however, it would make my code cleaner if I just used something from Specflow.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an internal Stopwatch on the ScenarioContext: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow/ScenarioContext.cs#L57

If you provide a PR that makes the Elapsed property of it accessible for the outside, I am happy to merge it in.

Comment: I ended up with this solution. It isn't exactly what I was hoping for... however it works just fine.